# What is the type of this time/datetime?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and currently i am going to extract the value of the time into date and time. Any kind of format is okay.

> Enddate:   {time: 1590076800000, isToday: false, title: "22",
>   subTitle: "", selected: true, …}

What is the type of this `time: 1590076800000` ? And how can you convert it to normal date and time in ionic 4. I have tried toString(),tolocalestring(),toUtc() .

And im dying to know what is the type/format is it. And why does it have to be in this format when sending data/receiving data on datetime.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is datetime in milliseconds, you can get it with new DateTime('159007...').toUtc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
currentTime = 1590076800000;
console.log(new Date(1590076800000), ' : new date');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toDateString(), ' : toDateString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toGMTString(), ' : toGMTString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toISOString(), ' : toISOString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toLocaleDateString(), ' : toLocaleDateString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toLocaleString(), ' : toLocaleString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toString(), ' : toString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toUTCString(), ' : toUTCString()');
console.log(new Date(1590076800000).toTimeString(), ' : toTimeString()');
```